# RobotFramework RIDE cannot import library

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have a file right here: `Library ../../MyLib/My_Lib.py`, and I try to import the python file in RIDE, but RIDE still report "FAIL : `No keyword with name '****' found"`, and this keyword is defined in the `My_Lib.py`, seems RIDE cannot find the python file.

I using `python 2.7.8+Robot Framework 3.1.2+windows server 2012r2`. I even selected `Library -> Name -> Browse` in RIDE, but the error still there and this whole robot test case folder is copied from another server which is working fine

Can anyone suggest what have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! I have worked this out, if anyone else meets the same issue, you can click `Tools->view RIDE Log`, to see what's happening there. For my case, it's because I didn't install thrift but the My_Lib.py obviously used thrift module, so the My_Lib.py compile failed with "No module named thrift.Thrift".

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the Python library was created to work with Python 3.x.x leading it to not work on your Python 2.7.8? See https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Check what python version is being run on the other server where the test is running fine. You might need to update your local Python version.

Also, you could try running the Robot test outside of RIDE just in case. You may do so by navigating to the test folder where the `.robot` file resides and running the following command:

```
robot test_file_name.robot
```

See if you get the same error that way. Please report back after doing the mentioned checks and we can continue debugging, my reputation doesn't let me comment on your question so I will just update the answer as we go along.

Comment: the other server has the same python version and robot version, and they are both window server 2012r2. I didn't find any file with suffix ".robot" in both server, but I do find  a .tsv file when I  right click one of my test suit and ->Open containing folder, and I use " robot test_file_name.tsv" , it sitll report no keywords with name "***" found

Comment: I have worked this out, thanks for the help, sincerely! :)